# I have a list of ListTiles, how to put them into my Drawer? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a drawer with dynamic data.

I have this:

```
  var menuOptionsNames = ["StartEndDay", "Journal"];

  List<Widget> createListTiles() {
    var menuOptions = [];

    for (var opt in menuOptionsNames)
      menuOptions.add(ListTile(title: Text(opt)));

    return menuOptions;
  }
```

Then I got this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ........
          ........

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

After the DrawerHeader I want to put the ListTiles I build up in `createListTiles`. The result should be like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(title: Text(menuOptionsNames[0]),),
          ListTile(title: Text(menuOptionsNames[1]),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But I don't find the way to do it... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```dart
  child: ListView(
    // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text('Drawer Header'),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      for (menuOptionsName in menuOptionsNames) // this line
          ListTile(
            title: Text('$menuOptionsName'),
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app.
            },
          ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like map to create a list of ListTile children's.
For example:

```
Column(
                children: ["StartEndDay", "Journal"]
                    .map((e) => ListTile(
                          title: Text(e),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              )
```